# How to fetch and display data from multiple endpoints in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have two endpoints. I want to fetch data from them at once and display in one element, for example display data from one table and name from another if the product id is the same.
This is how I do this now for one endpoint:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import products from '../apis/apiURLS'
import './Products.css';

const Products = () => {
    const [productInfo,setProductInfo] = useState([]);

    const fetchProducts  = async () =>{
        const response = await products.get('/products/')
        setProductInfo(response.data)
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchProducts()
    },[])

    return (
      <div>
      <h1 className = "header">Products</h1>      
      {productInfo.map(products=> {
        return (
          

      <div className="productInfo">
        {console.log(products)}
        <p>Date: {products.date}</p>

      </div>
          
      )

        
})}
</div>
    )}

export default Products
```

**EDIT**
Products endpoint has those fields: `date, product_id` and Stock endpoint has fields: `product_id, name` and product_id is the foreign key to Stock.
I was trying to add another async function for second endpoint:

```
const [stockInfo, setStockInfo] = useState([]);
const fetchStock  = async () =>{
      const response = await stock.get('/stock/')
      setStockInfo(response.data)
  }
    useEffect(()=>{
      fetchStock()
  },[])
```

But I can't map it correctly to display in one element. What I want to achieve is:

```
<p>Product: {stock.name}, {products.date}</p>
```

Comment: Can you show your attemp and expected result? You only show what you currently have working and we don't know what you expect to be the outcome of the mapping. How do these depend on each other?

Comment: @zero298 I added some details, I hope it is clear now

Comment: Do you have some sort of id in your enteties? So you can find stock that is related to product? LIke this: `const stock = stocks.find(s => s.id === product.id)`. You could put this in you `.map()`.

Comment: Why are you not fetching the all the data in one request?

Comment: thank you @Eggy but I think `find()` returns only first record which fits the statement and I need all of them

Answer (score 1):

If you consider that the result of requesting to both APIs are dependants, you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to ensure that the fetch completes successfully for both endpoints.

Thereafter you can merge the results by using the `product_id` field and a single `useState` hook to set the combined data in the component state.

For example,

```
const combineUsingProductIdField = (products, stocks) => {
  const keyByProductIdField = (previousValue, currentValue) => ({
    ...previousValue,
    [currentValue.product_id]: currentValue,
  });
  const stocksByProductId = stocks.reduce(keyByProductIdField, {});

  const productsWithStock = products.map(product => ({
    product,
    stock: stocksByProductId[item.product_id],
  }));
  return productsWithStock;
};

const Products = () => {
  const [productsWithStock, setProductsWithStock] = useState([]);

  const fetchProductsWithStock = () => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      return await products.get('/products/');
    };
    const fetchStocks = async () => {
      return await stock.get('/stock/');
    };

    try {
      const [_products, _stocks] = await Promise.all([
        fetchProducts,
        fetchStocks,
      ]);
      setProductsWithStock(combineUsingProductIdField(products, stocks));
    } catch (err) {
      // log to error reporting;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductsWithStock();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="header">Products</h1>
      {productsWithStock.map(({ product, stock }) => {
        return (
          <div className="productInfo">
            <p>
              Product: {stock.name}, {product.date}
            </p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

I recommend having a single API endpoint that returns this combined data if you can.
That way you would be relying on already existing relationship defined in your data models to pull the stock data for each product.